# Vuejs + Vuetify include an image inside an svg circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm actually trying to figure out how to do something like the image below with Vuetify.

[image]

So i tried a bunch of things but no ones worked. This is my last try :

```
<v-flex
  xs12
  sm4
  md4
  align-center
  justify-center
  text-xs-center>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" class="dotted-circle">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="75">
      <v-img
        :src="profilePic"
        aspect-ratio="1"
        max-height="100"
        max-width="100"
        class="grey lighten-2 rounded-img">
      </v-img>
    </circle>
  </svg>
</v-flex>
```

But this is just showing me my dotted circle and my image seem to be hidden behind it. There's the result :

[image]

And the html result :

[image]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: where is the image extension?

Comment: It's a vue variable from the data component. Plus, i'm sure the image path is correct because with other trys i used to have it visible.

Comment: how the browser is rendering this code? the output

Comment: I'v edited the post to show you the output. The blue line is the div containing image after compliation.

Comment: Did you try with `v-avatar` ? If so, can we have a reproducible CodePen with your issue ?

Comment: your image it's a background-image in a element without width and height, that's why you not see him, he don't have any size.